# Animation stops other UI elements from responding

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, animation

I'm trying to update my background color every 3 seconds using timer and calculating random color values and assign them to the background. I have done this but the thing is when I run my code on the main thread my `UITextField` won't respond anymore!

```
//
//  ViewBG.swift
//  E-Sign
//
//  Created by shayan rahimian on 1/30/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 shayan rahimian. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController{
    @objc func changeBG(){
        //background style!

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            let red   = Float((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0
            let green = Float((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0
            let blue  = Float((arc4random() % 256)) / 255.0
            let alpha = Float(1.0)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0, options:[.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: CGFloat(alpha))}, completion:nil)
            }
        }
        //end of background style
    }

    @objc func Blur(){
        //Blur BackGround
        let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurview = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
        blurview.frame = self.view.frame
        blurview.alpha = 0.7
        self.view.insertSubview(blurview, at: 0)
        //End of Blur
    }

    @objc func DoBG(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Blur()
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(UIViewController.changeBG), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
}
```

the background works fine, but my textfields wont edit! is there any way to change background color in background thread or any work arounds?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1) remove `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async` (for such operations you don't really need it), keep only the `main.async`

2) disable the interaction on `blurview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, I don't know how is your hierarchy, but might be harmful if it gets the touch in place of some other subviews.

3) your timer it's calling `changeBG` every 3 seconds, such function starts an animation with `repeat, .autoreverse`: I guess this is a bad mechanism (you might freeze the `ViewController` or crash the app) since you are keep adding animations that are looping [forever](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622487-repeat).

4) change the options of your animation in `[.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]`

Comment: thanks for your reply, 1.thanks for your suggestion i have removed it but that does'nt work. 2.all user interactions are enabled. 3.any suggestion for changing my background color?

Comment: @sci3nt15t Yes, but first try to comment the `UIView.animate`, let's see if it helps to solve your main problem. Then we focus to find a better animation

Comment: i have commented the uiview.animated line and i just kept my backgroundcolor line and i have set timer to change my background color every 3 second and every thing is working fine now. the only problem is the animation!

Comment: @sci3nt15t Cool, let me fix such animation. Just a moment

Comment: @sci3nt15t found the problem: `allowUserInteraction`. Check suggestion 4. Let me know if it helps.